# Когда доктор вошел, она вспыхнула(,) и глаза ее наполнились слезами

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Из "Анны Карениной":

> Когда доктор вошел, она **вспыхнула, и глаза** ее наполнились слезами.

Как изменится смысл предложения, если убрать запятую перед "и"?

> Когда доктор вошел, она **вспыхнула и глаза** ее наполнились слезами.

Я полагаю, что технически второй вариант правильный, поскольку перед двумя простыми предложениями есть придаточное, которое можно считать общим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае мы будем иметь последовательность из трёх действий.

Во втором случае мы будем иметь последовательность из первого действия и двух последующих, случившихся единовременно.

Если написать проще, то ситуации у нас здесь две разные:

1) Доктор вошёл, и в этот момент она вспыхнула. После этого глаза её наполнились слезами. При этом слезами они могли наполниться **уже после того**, как доктор вошёл. Предложение акцентирует внимание **только** на одновременности вхождения доктора и вспыхивания.

2) Доктор входит, и на это **разом в тот же момент** отвечают две реакции: вспыхивание и слёзы в глазах.

Answer (score 2):

***Когда доктор вошел, она вспЫхнула, и глаза ее наполнились слезАми.***

При формальном (техническом) решении можно сделать вывод, что запятая не ставится.

Но вот **формальность в этой теме весьма нежелательна**. Это правило должно применяться с учетом семантики и интонационной структуры.

**По смыслу** здесь автор изображает **последовательность** эмоций: сначала вспыхнуло лицо, потом глаза наполнились слезами. Такая реакция не может быть одномоментной.

**С точки зрения интонации** эти два предложения нежелательно  и неудобно читать в одну фразу, без паузы. Здесь логическими ударениями выделяются оба действия, в то время как при отсутствии запятой ударение будет стоять только в конце фразы.